# jQuery effects don't work when I add a speed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery (and javascript for  that matter), so this is probably just something stupid I'm doing, but it's really annoying me!

All I'm trying to do is add a speed to jQuery's hide and show functions.  The code I'm using is:

```
for (var i in clouds) {
    $(clouds[i]).click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

to hide clouds when they're clicked on, and

```
function fadeLogo(state) { 
    var element=document.getElementById('logo');

    if (state=='home') {
        element.hide;
        element.src='images/home.png';
        element.show;
    }

    else {
        element.hide;
        element.src='images/webNameLogo.png';
        element.show;
    }
}
```

to hide an image, change it and then show it again.  This is called by

```
onMouseOver=fadeLogo('home') onMouseOut=fadeLogo('logo')
```

This works fine, but happens instantaneously.  Whenever I try to include a speed, either as 'slow', 'fast' or in milliseconds, it won't work, they just stay in their original states.  Even adding hide() without a speed throws up an error in Safari's error console:

TypeError: Result of expression 'element.hide' [undefined] is not a function.

No errors are reported for the clouds, they just sit there not doing anything!

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

EDIT:

Now have this for the image change:

```
$(function() { //This function fades the logo to the home button on mouseover

    $('.logo').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(
            'slow',
            function () {
                $(this).attr ('src','images/home.png').fadeIn('slow');
            });
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(
            'slow',
            function () {
                $(this).attr('src','images/webNameLogo.png').fadeIn('slow');
            });
    });
});
```

Which fades the image out and in no problem, but doesn't change between the 2 images...
Oops, should have been #logo.  Got that one working now, onto the pesky clouds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [hide()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide#speedcallback) method is used like so:

```
for (var i in clouds) {
    $(clouds[i]).click(function() {
    $(this).hide( 'slow' ); // or you can pass the milliseconds
    });
}
```

As for the image hiding you should do something like this:

```
$( 'selector for your image' ).hide (
    'slow',
    function () {
        $( this ).attr ( 'src', 'images/other.png' ).show ( 'slow' );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I've tried adding 'slow' to the clouds as you suggested, but when I do nothing happens when I click on them.

As for the images, I've edited my post to show the full code I'm using (and replaced toggle with hide/show in case it somehow ends up in the wrong state).  Like the clouds, it works, but not when I add a speed...

Comment: You are mixing jQuery and JavaScript methods. JavaScript does not have a show/hide method. You must "convert" your DOM object to a jQuery object then you can use those methods. Also where does `clouds` come from?

Comment: Hmmm ok.  I've defined an array containing 4 cloud classes for manipulation later on in the script:  

var clouds=[".cloud1",".cloud2",".cloud3",".cloud4"];

Comment: Try putting a `alert()` inside the `click` function to see if it even gets triggered ...

Comment: Put an alert in and it is getting triggered but they're still just sitting there

Comment: What kind of HTML elements are your clouds? Any special CSS that they have?